# Converting array from php query to usable javascript format

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

How do I take my php array I've got from query and make it look like this:

```
["14-11-2016","15-11-2016"]
```

I've tried doing this:

```
$result=$connection->query("select day from blockades");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo json_encode($row['day']);
echo ",";
}
```

It gives me:

```
"1-11-2016","2-11-2016","3-11-2016","4-11-2016",
```

But when I try to put it in javascript array

```
var Array=<?php 
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo json_encode($row['day']);
} 
?>
console.log(Array)
```

It obviously doesn't work. Console logs this:

```
function Array() { [native code] }
jquery-ui.js:9244 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined(…)
```

Since the console.log gives nothing I have no idea if it even writes anything to that js array, can anyone help?

Comment: [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is a global object in Javascript. Also for a well formed js array you are missing `[` `]` .

Comment: and don't build the Array manually. Build the desired Array in PHP and encode the whole thing at once `$arr=array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) $arr[]=$row['day'];
echo json_encode($arr);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are encoding each separate item, but you need to encode the entire list of items.

```
<?php
// Create array to hold all items.
$days = array();
$result = $connection->query("select day from blockades");
// Add the days to the array.
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $days[] = ($row['day']);
}

// Output the JavaScript variable:
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var Days=<?php echo json_encode($days) ?>;
console.log(Days);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

It appears that you have altered the prototype of `Array`, and it could be because of using

```
var Array=<?p
```

You need to use `array` or any other variable like `arr`

```
var arr=<?p
```

and then

```
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Now the error changed to "undefined", does that mean my arr is empty?

Comment: @Bonana could be, check the output of this php code in your developer tools.